# Play an online audio file in Java

Tags: java, mp3, javasound

I am trying to play an online audio file in Java   Here's a link to [the file](http://zekr.org/download/recit/ghamdi-40kbps-online.properties) and this can be run from Java code.  How can I play this from my Java code without downloading it to my PC?

Comment: *"can be run from java code"*  How?  It seems a descriptor for some type of 'streaming'.  MP3s are referenced in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Playing Back Audio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html) tutorial. Here is an [example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.sound.sampled/StreamAudio.html).

Answer (score 0):

What about [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-135334.html) ([JMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework))?